# Assigning id to two elements present in a single column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing some issue in assigning id to two elements present in a single column. One element is dropdown and other is a text element. Actually I achieved this in first scenario but i am facing some issues in second scenario. Please help me guys..

Scenario 1:

```
    <td> 
        <select name="fmeaEntityForm[0].subSystem.id" id="subSystem0" onchange="getsubSystemFunction(this)">
            <option value="-1">
               <spring:message code="label.fmea.select.subSystem" />
            </option>
            <c:forEach items="${subSystemList}" var="ss">
                  <option value="${ss.id}">${ss.subSystem}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            <option value="0">
                <spring:message code="label.fmea.select.other" /></option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="fmeaEntityForm[0].subSystem.subSystem" id="subSystemText0" placeholder="Enter Sub-system if selected other"/>
   </td>
```

In scenario one i can easily access first element by : `table.rows[rowCount].cells[cellNumber].childNodes[0]` and second element by `table.rows[rowCount].cells[cellNumber].lastChild` .

Scenario 2: I need to align this dropdown and text box so i used two classes to align both of the elements parallel. Now both elements are aligned properly but I am not able to access both these elements

```
<td> 
      <div class="element1">
         <select name="fmeaEntityForm[0].subSystem.id" id="subSystem0" onchange="getsubSystemFunction(this)">
            <option value="-1">
                 <spring:message code="label.fmea.select.subSystem" />
            </option>
            <c:forEach items="${subSystemList}" var="ss">
                <option value="${ss.id}">${ss.subSystem}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            <option value="0">
                <spring:message code="label.fmea.select.other" />
            </option>
        </select>
     </div>
     <div class="element2">
          <input type="text" name="fmeaEntityForm[0].subSystem.subSystem" id="subSystemText0" placeholder="Enter Sub-system if selected other"/>
     </div>
</td>
```

css

```
.element1
{
    display:in-line;
    float:left;
}

.element2 
{
    margin-left:5px;
    display:in-line;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in "scenario 2" use..

`table.rows[rowCount].cells[cellNumber].childNodes[0].childNodes[0]` to get the select element, and

`table.rows[rowCount].cells[cellNumber].lastChild.childNodes[0]` to get the input element

Comment: Thank you for your reply table.rows[rowCount].cells[cellNumber].lastChild.childNodes[0] for input element is working fine but table.rows[rowCount].cells[cellNumber].childNodes[0].childNodes[0] is not working

Comment: any comments for table.rows[rowCount].cells[cellNumber].childNodes[0].childNodes[0] is not working ?